# What is the best way to handle a join / group_concat query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, concat, group-concatenation

I am looking for some feedback regarding the best way to handle the following (simplified for this example) situation.

I have 3 tables: tasks, assignees, and users

```
---tasks----
id, task, completed

---assignees----
user_id, task_id

---users---
id, name
```

I need to select tasks with concatenated user names of assignees, like so

```
tasks.task  |   assigned_names.names   
---------------------------------------
"My task"   |   "Joe Schmoe, Bob Mcbart, Sally McGuire"
```

Here is what I have currently

```
SELECT tasks.task, assigned_names.names

FROM tasks

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT( users.name SEPARATOR ',' ) AS names,
      assignees.task_id
      FROM assignees
      LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = assignees.user_id
      GROUP BY assignees.task_id
   
) assigned_names ON assigned_names.task_id = tasks.id

WHERE tasks.completed IS NULL
```

My main concern is that the assignees table has hundreds of thousands of records, and doing a group on the whole table every time seems like not a good idea.

Is there a better strategy?

Also, I would be happy to rephrase my question title if someone could suggest better language.

Thanks!

Comment: Why use a subselect and not join the two tables directly?

Comment: Would that be more efficient?

I was doing that at first, but I got the following error

Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tasks.task' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.

I don't want to group by tasks.task as well, as it is a text column

Comment: You won't know until you try (and look at the query plan as well).

Answer (score 0):

Simplicity is beautify. Multiple `JOIN`s are allowed. There is no need to the JOINs to be `LEFT JOINS` as you want data that maches always.

```
SELECT tasks.task, GROUP_CONCAT( users.name SEPARATOR ',' ) AS names,
FROM assignees
JOIN tasks ON assignees.task_id = tasks.id
JOIN users ON assignees.user_id = users.id
WHERE tasks.completed IS NULL
GROUP BY assignees.task_id
```

Comment: If you get a a group by non-aggregate field in result error, using `tasks.id` in the `GROUP BY ` is equivalent.